# snmpget с числовым oid вместо имени параметра

Tags: linux, openwrt, snmp

Добрый день.

Пытаюсь из под openwrt запустить команду snmpget.
Мне выпадает множество сообщений начинающихся с

```
Cannot adopt OID in SNMPv2-MIB:
```

И в конце:

```
There is no such variable name in this MIB
```

Насколько я понимаю, система пытается искать введённый параметр в базах, чтобы сопоставить ему числовой oid.
Проблема в том, что я и так уже пытаюсь ввести числовой oid в качестве параметра.

Неужели, snmpget не поддерживает использование числовых oid? Во всех примерах, которые я нагуглил, используются именованные параметры...

Возможно, числовые oid просто следует вводить, используя какой-то особый синтаксис? Гугл молчит на эту тему, уже два часа бьюсь...

Answer (score 1):

> Неужели, snmpget не поддерживает использование числовых oid?

Ну почему же ?! Я лично регулярно использую запросы вида:

```
snmpget -v2c -c public 172.16.17.235 1.3.6.1.4.1.19707.7.7.2.1.4.112.0
```

И всё работает абсолютно нормально.

Comment: Рад, что у вас всё работает нормально... Но у меня такой вариант выдаёт длинный список сообщений про MIB. Вчера целый день бился с этим и так ничего не получается...

Comment: **у меня такой вариант выдаёт длинный список сообщений про MIB** - кто выдаёт? Субагент ? А тот OID, что вы запрашиваете - он действительно известен субагенту? Как Вы его информировали о Вашем поддереве OID?

Comment: Проще говоря: если ругается действительно субагент, то связь с ним устанавливается и он живой. Если он ругается на OID - значит он не знает таких! А раз так - значит Вы не настроили его MIB.